# Load Highscore on Main Menu of game SWIFT XCODE

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I have created a game and I already know how to load and save the high score for the game and I want to know how to display the high score on the main screen (the main menu is the first view to appear) and the high score is saved on the 2nd view which is the game view is there a way to pass the data to the main menu without changing to the second view? Please help, thanks to anyone who replies!

Comment: You need to have a manager that manages the scores and both of your second view controller and main view controller (all of you view controllers) use that manager for reading and saving (and also doing other operations with scores). Did you tried this?

Comment: @HuseinBehboodiRad thanks for the reply, I have never heard of adding a manager what is that and how would I create one?

Comment: it is only a separate class that you use it for managing your logic. Your model class in MVC. I share you a simple class as an answer now. wait a minute

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSUserdefaults for this task. In your second view set your Highscore value into NSUserdefaults like below,

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(YourValue, forKey:"HighScore")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

And then in your first view's viewdidload method just add this,

```
if(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("HighScore") as! String != "") {
       self.yourLabelName.text = HigheScore
       } else {
         print("No highscore set.")
       }
```

Comment: It is better to put this code in a manager class and do not call NSUserDefaults directly in all view controllers

Comment: I am not sure how to get this to work, I created the NSuserDefault in the 2nd view, however in the second view I cannot get the line        self.yourLabelName.text = HigheScore to work, thanks for the reply by the way!

Comment: Nope you don't have to do the exact self.yourLabelName.text = HigheScore line of code. Thats an example. What happen in that code line is we are setting the value which is inside HigheScore to a UILabel called yourLabelName. To check this working just remove that line and add, 
print(HigheScore)
Then you can check this is working or not.

Comment: Hey so i tried what you are talking about and this is the error i got and my code  http://imgur.com/a/wtgJa

Comment: if(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("HighScore") as! NSNumber != 0) {
       self.yourLabelName.text = HigheScore
       } else {
         print("No highscore set.")
       }

Change your code to above.

Comment: I now get an error saying "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(50, forKey:"HighScore")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize() 

Replace above code and check. This will hardcode your Highscore as 50. You have to assign proper variable later.

Comment: Well, create variable called HighScore on top of your first view controller ( after the import frameworks - before the class starts),
var  HighScore : NSNumber = 50

Then in your second view change your code to this
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(HighScore, forKey:"HighScore") NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like below class that has at least two methods  `saveHighScore` and `readHighScore` and in all viewControllers and also all other classed that you want to access the score create an instance of this class and call the methods you want.

**Swift**

```
public class ScoreManager: NSObject {

    let highScoreDefaultKey = "HighScoreDefaultKey"

    public func saveHighScore (highScore: NSNumber) {

        //This method includes your implementation for saving the high score
        //You can use UserDefault or any other data store like CoreData or
        //SQLLit or etc. For example I added UserDefault

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(highScore, forKey: highScoreDefaultKey)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

    }

    public func getHighScore() -> NSNumber?
    {
        //This method includes your implementation for reading the high score

        let highScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(highScoreDefaultKey)

        if (highScore != nil) {
            return highScore as! NSNumber?;
        }else
        {
            //No high score availble, so return nil
            return nil;
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
    var highScore = ScoreManager().getHighScore()

    ScoreManager().saveHighScore(NSNumber(int: 120))
```

**Objective-C**

```
#import "ScoreManager.h"

#define USERDEFAULTS_HIGHSCRORE_KEY @"highScore"

@implementation ScoreManager

- (void) saveHighScore:(NSNumber *) highScore
{
    //This method includes your implementation for saving the high score
    //You can use UserDefault or any other data store like CoreData or
    //SQLLit or etc. For example I added UserDefault

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:highScore forKey:USERDEFAULTS_HIGHSCRORE_KEY];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

- (NSNumber *) readHighScore
{

    //This method includes your implementation for reading the high score

    NSNumber *highScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:USERDEFAULTS_HIGHSCRORE_KEY];
    if (highScore) {
        return highScore;
    }else
    {
        //No high score availble, so return nil

        return nil;
    }

}

@end
```

The advantage are that:

1- The implementation of your read and write process is only in one place and you can change it (for example switch from `UserDefaults` to `CoreData`) whenever you wants and do not worry about to change all places that you are working with Score

2- Simply call only one method when you want to access to score or write it.

3- Simply debug it when you see a bug or something like this.

Notice: If you are worry about `synchronization` it is better to use a `singleton` class that manages this matter.

Comment: Hey, first of all I appreciate the help. Second of all, I am pretty new to coding so i have a few questions about this, first off where should this code go? Should i make a new swift file for this or place it in all of the files I already created? and also if i was trying to call the save high score method would I write in [[[ScoreManager alloc] init] saveHighScore]Also this is how i save the HS does this work with ur way? let bestScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
bestScoreDefault.setValue(iBestScore, forKey: "BestScore")
bestScoreDefault.synchronize()

Comment: The code is objective-c class. Let me share the swift version of the class

Comment: Now please check the swift class. You should create a new class and call the methods that you want for read or write anywhere that you want to work with score

Comment: Thanks! Do I only need to add this code to one view controller file and it will work in all views files and how do i call the readHighScore and saveHighScoe functions? I tried saveHighScore(highScore: NSNumber) but that does not work

Comment: I also added swift usage too

Comment: So I have been trying to figure this out and I am just kind of lost, here are screenshots of the code I have. I am not getting errors, but the high score is not saving or doing anything, would you be able to try and tell me where I went wrong? http://imgur.com/a/iHKrH